# p4d server won't start (Linux) - issues began when trying to run a Linux update

Tags: perforce

I have a Linux server I setup to run perforce a few weeks ago. Been running fine for myself and one other person. I'm fairly new to linux and perforce both, as well as server concepts so this has been a steep learning curve. I was told to regularly update the linux server, so a few days ago I did.

When updating, I used the commands "apt-get update" and "apt-get dist-upgrade". during the second command, it errored out on the helix-p4dctl startup with the error "SSL connect to ssl:1666 failed (connection reset by peer) Remove SSL protocol prefix from P4PORT or fix the TLS settings".

For starters, I'm confused why doing an update is causing a problem like this given that it was working previously, unless the update some how eliminated some previously saved settings?

After much digging, I've been able to at least get passed that error message (although I'm not 100% sure how, I think it was by defining P4PORT in the config file) and now if I try to run the dist-upgrade command again I still get a failure while trying to setup the p4dctl service and it doesn't tell me much BUT just below it there is a message stating that helix-p4d failed because of a dependency on helix-p4dctl, and then goes on to say that helix-p4dctl is not configured yet.

I'm not sure how p4dctl cannot already be configured from when I initially set it all up, unless by "configured" it actually means started? As far as I can tell everything looks setup correctly on the p4dctl stuff.

There is also a part that tells me to check journalctl, but when I do there doesn't seem to be anything useful in there. Just similar messages to what it's giving me here.

EDIT: After some more digging I found this post: [Perforce stopped connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76327707/perforce-stopped-connecting)

It contains a similar issue, so I searched for a .xu file and found one at /opt/perforce/servers//state.xu with only read permissions on it. I'm unsure of what the permissions should be as it isn't stated in that other post or even if it's the same file as the other post seems to be in a different location. If any one knows what permissions that file should have or has a perforce server running on linux and can check theirs I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Feel a bit silly it took so long, but once I figured out how to access the log, the answer was right there.

For anyone in the future with a similar issue and similarly limited knowledge:

find / -type d -name “log”

that will give you the path for the log file.
Then use nano to open the log and read it: nano /path/to/file/log

Once in the log file, go to the bottom to see the latest results and it gave me the exact line to run to fix it. (I would put it here but 1. I don't have it in front of me now that I've restarted the server and 2. I don't want to post a command that may not be your actual problem and inadvertently cause you to have more issues. Better to just check your log to see if it's the same problem).